# null Extras when calling for ACTION_PICK

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I call the gallery with an intent like this :

```
        Intent picturePickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    picturePickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    picturePickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    picturePickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    picturePickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    picturePickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", PHOTO_SIZE);
    picturePickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", PHOTO_SIZE);
    picturePickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    startActivityForResult(picturePickerIntent, IMAGE_GALERY_REQUEST);
```

And then I get the result:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_GALERY_REQUEST) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                bm = extras.getParcelable("data");
                photoView.setImageBitmap(bm);
                if (avatarSelected != null) {
                    avatarSelected.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
                this.avatarSelected = null;
            }else{
                // Sometimes, the photo isn't loaded
                Toast.makeText(this, "The photo has not been loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

On certain devices, this code works like a charm, on others it shows the toast every time, and on a 6.0 emulator it works literally once out of two.

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to have no problem but you did forget about dynamic permissions which will always return null.Read this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {


    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

    }
}
```

Basically you need to ask for permissions dynamically for android 6 and plus .